# NetLogo - Finding Turtles Within 2 Squares

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to find out how to check if there are any turtles near another (which we will call the base turtle, or base). I need this to include diagonals, as I am spawning people around these bases and so need 1 full square around the base empty. Thus. when spawning bases I need to make sure there are no others within 2 squares, including diagonal.

I tried using "turtles in-radius (2,3,4,...)" and it doesn't work, since it seems that the radius command is circular. How would I go about this?

Comment: A relevant code example is Moore & Von Neumann Example, in the Code Examples section of NetLogo's Models Library. (A square neighborhood is called a “Moore neighborhood”.)

Answer (score 1):

NetLogo's `neighbors` gives you the 8 patches surrounding the patch the turtle is on.  Do you need the 16 surrounding patches, or will 8 do?

A simple procedure for neighbors16 in a non-wrapping world might be

```
to-report neighbors16
  ; can be called by a patch or a turtle
  ; assumes there is no wrapping of the world
  let xm max (list (pxcor - 2) min-pxcor)
  let xh min (list (pxcor + 2) max-pxcor)
  let ym max (list (pycor - 2) min-pycor)
  let yh min (list (pycor + 2) max-pycor)

  let ptchs no-patches
  foreach (range xm (xh + 1) 1) [x ->
    foreach (range ym (yh + 1) 1) [y ->
      set ptchs (patch-set patch x y ptchs)
    ]
  ]
  report ptchs with [self != patch [pxcor] of myself [pycor] of myself]
end
```

Hope this helps,
Charles

Comment: Instead of `let base patch-here` and `let xm [pxcor] of base - 2`, you could just say `let xm pxcor - 2`. A turtle has direct access to the variables of the patch it is standing on.

Comment: This code looks like it would work, but it also looks to me like it would be very slow, since `patches with ...` has to check every patch in the world to see if it qualifies.

Comment: Responding to Seth's always cogent observations, I've edited my answer to be (I think) more efficient.  It can be called by either a turtle or a patch.

Comment: Nice! You might also enjoy looking at the code in Moore & Von Neumann Example, which does something similar but using `at-points`.